# Where have DotNetNuke 7 files gone?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Am trying upgrade my installation of DotNetNUke 7. When I go to the dnn website it only offers me the installer, which isn't what I want. Where can I just get the installation files?

Comment: If you are "upgrading" be sure to use the Upgrade package, not the Install package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are on CodePlex: http://dnnplatform.codeplex.com/releases/view/110757

Check under Downloads from the main site: http://dnnplatform.codeplex.com/